# General question about Amazon Alexa's "Next Intent" (using the skill kit)

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I currently try to build an alexa skill providing users with news information out of a DB.
I have 3 news topics in that DB:
- local
- global
- finance

So what I do currently is that if the user invoces the NewsIntent I collect all the data of all 3 topics, merge them together and provide that data as output via Alexa.

My question now is how would I integrate the NextIntent.

E.g. the user is not interested in the local news and would like to skip it.

My problem is, when an intent gets invoced teh I build up the response and return it back to Alexa. But in that case I would need to be able to send 3 responsed one after the other, right?

I do not know if my thoughts on that are correct or not.

If you have any idea please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: I would think for the first time user, we can start with local, ask they want to hear more about global or not and then finance. And the program will learn about end-user's habit and work accordingly as personality principle. Such as last time the user only interest in local not global, so likely he won't interested in global at all ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Alexa Session Attributes https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/manage-skill-session-and-session-attributes.html to store in which DB are you currently. Like `db: local`. Then when you receive  `AMAZON.NextIntent` you will check session attributes and based on them you will use expected database.

Comment: Ok - then my question is: if I have 3 entries in the database how can I invoce an intent which returns all 3 entries one after the other? because otherwise I cannot intercept with the nextintent (or do I think in the wrong way?)

Comment: @Kev, the question is if you want all news information send in one intent, or you want loop in the news using NextIntent and every time you will get a one news about db?